# Accessing a variable from server side on client side change

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

In my `file1.jsp` file I have populated a list of usernames in a dropdown. On the selection of a username I am trying to send the selected name as a parameter into one of my restful services found in `file2.java` that calls a query in `file3.java`.

**Order of operations**

1. select username
2. use username to get session
3. use session to get more info

**file1.jsp**

```
var global; //global variable
```

**file2.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "")
    @ResponseBody
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    public String getStuff(@RequestParam(required = false, value = "x") String x, HttpSession )
            throws JsonMappingException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        List<String> data = file3.getStuff(x);


    }
```

**file3.java**

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<String> getStuff(String x){
    Query query = em.createQuery("[stuff] WHERE global= :x");
    query.setParameter("x", x);
    List<String> queryResults = query.getResultList();
    return queryResults;
}
```

**Question:**

How do I access the variable and resend the query each selection change?

I have looked into making the javascript variable global, but I can't figure out how to actually access the variable. Note: i left out a lot of code.

Comment: Could you provide the jsp code? It's not clear what you are doing exactly.

Comment: @AdrianMitev I tried to clarify, I am having trouble explaining thoroughly.

Comment: You make an Ajax request.

Comment: What do you want to do with that list returned by getStuff() ?

Comment: @AdrianMitev I use a restful service so the data will get sent to `http://ip/stuff`